# Laravel 5.5 MultiAuth

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'd like to make one login page. I'm checking 2 databases and if user exists in any then I'd like make his logged. The problem is that both database has different structure different models. How after login I can force on laravel use 2 models to check logged user?

Comment: do you have different url or subdomain  ?

Comment: I have the same domain same url. I'm checking 2 databases. Standard users and second database. From each db user has with different privileges (admin/user).
I need to check in 2 because I have master db and slave only to read. This is client db with data to display in system and users ids.

Depends on user role he will redirect to different section after login.